# When I try to run my bash script it throws me an error like this

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```sh
case $choice in
1)
read -p "Enter the file to copy:" file
read -p "Enter the new file name:" newfile
$(cp file newfile)

;;

2)
read -p "Enter the file to move:" mvfile
read -p "Enter the file where to move:" newmv
$(mv mvfile newmv)

;;

3)
read -p "Enter the file name to remove:" filenm
$(rm filenm)

;;
esac
```

Error:

```
What do you want to do:
1) To copy from one file to another file
2) To move a file
3) To remove a file
**********************************************
Enter the choice:1
Enter the file to copy:common.txt
Enter the new file name:clone.txt
cp: cannot stat 'file': No such file or directory
root@root1-VirtualBox:/home/root1#
```

(when I try to run this it throws me an error like this !!)

Comment: `file` is a string. You want the variable previously registered in `read` command => `$file`.

Comment: @Zeitounator i have tryed that but it's not working

Comment: "It's not working" does not accurately describe the problem you have.

Comment: @Zeitounator now it's working

Comment: I'd recommend a bash tutorial; you seem to be missing the basics. A tutorial will probably help with many other bash problems you're about to encounter.

Comment: @Robert no just now i'm learning bash ,, i'm new to bash that's why :)

Answer (score 4):

`file` and `newfile` are variables, you need to address them with a `$`:

```sh
$(cp $file $newfile)
```

Comment: yah,, now it's working thank you :)